# Cannot open firefox browser via X11

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, amazon-ec2, x11

When I try to start firefox on ec2 instance (centos/7) via X11, I got an error.
Is there a way to solve this?
I'm already confirmed that other GUI application, sucy as xeyes or eog, can be launched.

### Env

ec2 side

OS: Centos 7.3.1611 (Core)
SELinux: Enforcing
xauth version: 1.0.9
xterm version: X.Org 7.6.0(295)
xorg-x11-apps.x86_64: 7.7-6.el7

```
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

local side

OS:  Mac OS X 10.11.6
XQuartz version: 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)

```
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Apple:
 Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

### Reproduction scenario

```
# ec2 side
sudo yum -y install xauth xterm xorg-x11-apps xeyes
exit

# local side
ssh -X fhiyo@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

# ec2 side
xeyes  # OK

sudo yum -y install eog
eog path/to/sample.png  # OK

sudo yum -y install firefox
$ firefox
[Parent 20819] WARNING: pipe error (36): Connection reset by peer: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.2.0/firefox-52.2.0esr/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 322

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x46000E,name=PContent::Msg_NotifyLayerAllocated) Channel error: cannot send/recv

...

[Parent 20819] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.2.0/firefox-52.2.0esr/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 22

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2C0085,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

[image: firefox_crashed]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when launching Firefox version 52.3.0 with X11 forwarding on CentOS 7 :

*WARNING: pipe error (35): Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.3.0/firefox-52.3.0esr/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 322*

And same error (in french) on firefox "Gah, you tab just crash"

To correct this, i tried first to update all the package without success.
So i combined two solutions i found on the net :

1- I opened the "about:config" page (just type about:config in the url field then enter) and changed to "false" the 2 options browser.tabs.config.autostart and browser.tabs.config.autostart2

2- I opened the "about:support" page and click on "Repair Firefox..."

Then it works ! but i still have the  following problem : i need to do this each time i relaunch firefox; So i should not close all tabs.

Comment: as of July, 2019 I didn't find those exact options in the config, but switched everything, what mentioned 'autostart' to false (there was approx. 3 or 4 values). It helped, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Check your SELinux configuration. In special check that `mozilla_plugin_can_network_connect` is enabled. You can do: `getsebool mozilla_plugin_can_network_connect` if answer is `off` then do `setsebool -P mozilla_plugin_can_network_connect=1`. Then try again `firefox&`